# MacOS and JSVC: SCARD_E_NO_SERVICE: The Smart card resource manager is not running

Tags: macos, smartcard, jsvc

I got a JAR file that needs to run as a daemon in MacOS Sierra and I decided to use Apache Commons Daemon and JSVC for that purpose. I am aware that maybe JSVC is not really needed for this purpose (it seems only allows to open ports in a low range) and it is possible to achieve the same with system/launch so any help/solution with or without JSVC is appreciated.

This is how I am running the jar from the command line, and it works properly. It opens a WebSocket connection using port 8085 and waits for an incoming connection. Then, it connects to a smart card reader and gets some data from the card.

```
java -cp "myjar.jar:jars/*" full_class_name
```

Now, when I try to run the same jar with the Apache Commons Daemon interface and JSVC, the jar starts properly and it starts listening in port 8085.

```
./jsvc -debug -cp commons-daemon-1.1.0.jar:myjar.jar:jars/* -cwd . -pidfile /tmp/file.pid full_class_name
```

The issue is that, for some reason, there is an exception when trying to connect to the smart card reader.

```
INFORMACIÓN: WebSocket Registered apps: URLs all start with ws://localhost:8085
may 15, 2018 10:04:37 AM org.glassfish.tyrus.server.Server start
INFORMACIÓN: WebSocket server started.
LISTENING
Daemon started successfully
java_start done
Waiting for a signal to be delivered
create_tmp_file: /tmp/541.jsvc_up
jnasmartcardio.Smartcardio$EstablishContextException: jnasmartcardio.Smartcardio$JnaPCSCException: SCardEstablishContext got response 0x8010001d (SCARD_E_NO_SERVICE: The Smart card resource manager is not running.)
    at jnasmartcardio.Smartcardio$JnaTerminalFactorySpi.engineTerminals(Smartcardio.java:81)
    at javax.smartcardio.TerminalFactory.terminals(TerminalFactory.java:351)
    at apdu4j.TerminalManager.getTheReader(TerminalManager.java:228)
    at com.st.middleware.a.a.b.connect(SourceFile:24)
    at com.st.middleware.a.b.connect(SourceFile:18)
    at com.st.middleware.a.b.getCertificates(SourceFile:1024)
    at com.st.middleware.MiddlewareImpl.a(SourceFile:113)
    at com.st.middleware.MiddlewareImpl.getAuthCertificates(SourceFile:151)
    at com.st.communication.card.websocket.a.handleMessage(SourceFile:79)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
```

The fact that the jar works properly when running with java -jar makes me believe that the issue is something with the configuration. Any ideas on why the service is not available using JSVC?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same exception from jnasmartcardio under Linux. My solution was a missing native library. I installed pcscd and the exception was gone.